# funnel or checklist icon

Tags: icons, image, button

I am looking for an icon to act as filter button (which on click will show a box with the filter options)

So I've seen a couple of results on google for **filter icon** and I've only seen by now funnels and some checklists.

What is your opinion, what should I use as an icon for a filter button?

Comment: Hi w0rldart.  we recently determined that [questions on specific icons](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions) are unlikely to be useful to future visitors. As such, I'm closing this question. I'm glad you got you found the answer you sought, and agree, you can't go wrong with a funnel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funnel has become *the* symbol for filtering. There's no reason to be original with icons since people often can't infer their meaning without tooltips because of their experience with computers or cultural/language issues.

Comment: Also, see this article on icon design: http://uxmag.com/articles/realism-in-ui-design